# How to have the text of a button be the same size(width and height) of the button in kivy?

Tags: kivy

I'd like to be able to have the text of the button be as big as the button. And even if the button gets resized that would still be true.

Is it even possible in kivy?

I have googled it but didn't find anything. So here I am to ask for help.

Comment: You could show images of the various cases, for example if the width of the text does not fit in the button, the same with the height.

Comment: yeah, can you illustrate the kind of result you expect? Do you want the text to be stretched? the font to get as big as possible while keeping the text inside the borders? something else?

Comment: @Tshirtman - That's exactly what I want. I want the text inside the button to be the same size of the button while keeping the text inside the button. If the button gets resized so will the text inside it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but what happens about ratio? the text and the button can have a different width/height ratio? how is this resolved? is the text stretched to fit the button in both direction? or does it only go to only fit the limiting dimention and have space between text borders and button borders?

Comment: @Tshirtman - Yes the text and button can have a different width/height ratio, something that will look right. Yes, the text should be stretched in both directions to fit the button. Sorry for saying that I wanted the text to be the same size as the button. What I meant was the same size of the button minus some padding. Right now what happens is that if I resize the button small enough the text in it will not be totally inside the button, which is not the desired behavior. Thanks man for assisting me on this matter.

Comment: @eyllanesc - Thanks for trying to help...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a bit hacky, but works nicely enough imho.

So i had to copy the Button rule from style.kv, because i couldn't insert the Scale instruction at the right place to avoid changing the background overwise, and it was also actually necessary to change the texture position, but it wasn't that crazy.

The following code creates a dynamic class, inheriting from `Button`, with a few new properties, all computed except `keep_ratio` which allows the user to decide if the text always keeps its ratio, scaling both dimentions to the limiting one.

`x_ratio` and `y_ratio` compute the scale required to fit the texture in the current size in each direction (or 1 if it already fits), and `min_ratio` just takes the smaller of them, then `scale_x` and `scale_y` takes the corresponding value *or* the `min_ratio` if `keep_ratio` is True.

Then these `scale_x` and `scale_y` values are used in a `Scale` canvas instruction, and also in the `pos` of the `Rectangle` instruction to adjust it as needed (although i now see i could have used the `origin` option of `Scale` instead as well).

The rest of the kv code is just to demonstrate usage using a few sliders to force button's size and font_size to test the constraints, and a checkbox to decide if keep_ratio is True or False.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

KV = '''

<-ScaleButton@Button>:
    x_ratio: min(1, self.width / (self.texture_size[0] or 1))
    y_ratio: min(1, self.height / (self.texture_size[1] or 1))
    min_ratio: min(self.x_ratio or 1, self.y_ratio or 1)
    keep_ratio: False
    scale_x: (self.min_ratio or 1) if self.keep_ratio else self.x_ratio or 1
    scale_y: (self.min_ratio or 1) if self.keep_ratio else self.y_ratio or 1

    state_image: self.background_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_down
    disabled_image: self.background_disabled_normal if self.state == 'normal' else self.background_disabled_down

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        BorderImage:
            border: self.border
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: self.disabled_image if self.disabled else self.state_image
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

        PushMatrix
        Scale:
            x: self.scale_x or 1
            y: self.scale_y or 1

        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size
            pos:
                (
                int((self.center_x / (self.scale_x or 1)) - self.texture_size[0] / 2.),
                int((self.center_y / (self.scale_y or 1)) - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
                )

        PopMatrix


FloatLayout:
    ScaleButton:
        text: 'test ' * 5
        font_size: font_size.value
        size_hint: size_hint_x.value, size_hint_y.value
        pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .5)}
        keep_ratio: lock_ratio.active

    Slider:
        id: size_hint_y
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: None
        value: .5
        min: 0
        max: 1

    Slider:
        id: size_hint_x
        size_hint_y: None
        value: .5
        min: 0
        max: 1

    Slider:
        id: font_size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: None
        value: 20
        min: 10
        max: 1000
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}

    BoxLayout:
        size: self.minimum_size
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center': (.5, .8)}

        CheckBox:
            id: lock_ratio
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 20, 20
        Label:
            text: 'lock ratio'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
'''  # noqa


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(KV))
```

This applies a scaling to the OpenGl instructions, rather than changing the `font_size`, because i though it would be easier and more efficient (no re-creation of the texture when size constraints change), but another way could be to have a `max_font_size` instead of `font_size`, and compute `font_size` using the same kind of logic with `x_scale` and `y_scale`, but since that would alter the `texture_size`, it would require re-checking the original `texture_size` everytime the button's size change, or have an invisible texture of the original size around to compute the ratio against, and that did seem bothersome, for no obvious gain.

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much. That's more than what I needed. You are the man...I mean the Tshirtman...